# Is there one word that means 'to temporarily join'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

Is there a one-worded synonym for 'temporarily join'?

**Examples:**

- I want to *temporarily join* your team

Or a slightly different meaning;

- I want to *temporarily join* these two pieces of metal

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm... I can't think of any word for that since it's just an adverb explaining the verb, and it's hard to think of a single word doing it all at once. :-/

Comment: For the "joining a team" case the term *secondment* would be appropriate, as in "I want to be seconded to your team".

Comment: "I'm a temp on this team"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process of joining groups of humans and things are fairly distinct and probably call for different terms.

For humans, the verb *[substitute](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/substitute)*, or *sub* for short, may suit. The *Macmillan Dictionary* defines it as

> [INTRANSITIVE] to do someone else's job for a short period of time; 
>   substitute for: *Mark will substitute for me tomorrow.*

For objects, the verb *[tack](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/tack?)* may be suitable. According to *Collins*, it means

> to attach temporarily, as by sewing with long stitches

This can be applied to other materials, including metals, although some tacking processes (such as spot welding) may require a good bit of effort to reverse.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for something that is an *addition*, not a *substitute* but this might suffice.

Comment: In some circumstances, @Rupe's *secondment* might be appropriate, but it also suggests ongoing affiliation with another group that is lending the person to the new group.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to find one word that fits all you want but here are two words you can use in combinations or in proper context:

Hitch- to join something with a rope or to attach (a source of motive power) to a vehicle or instrument .(definition from merriam webster)

Patch - Connect by a temporary electrical, radio, or telephonic connection. (definition from oxford)

Examples:

My wagon was hitched to his van.

I am hitched to their team as a replacement.

You have to use your discretion when it comes to joining things like metals. You could say "I am bonding them for now" or "I am making a temporary joint." And when you means permanently you could say something ljke "I am welding them together."

Answer (score 1):

This all depends on the context you're trying to use it in, but a few phrases come to mind:

- join forces
- meet
- take part in
- support

More generally, you might want to look up "join" in a thesaurus, which is where I got all of these phrases.

Answer (score 0):

In your first context, the word

### *engage*

would be appropriate, if not too formal sounding.

Answer (score 0):

One term that might work, at least in the context given, is "**shadow**".  This sense of the word is defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shadow) as "[to] accompany (someone) in their daily activities at work in order to gain experience at or insight into a job".